# Any advice on how to use r.stats in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-processing, grass-gis

I am trying to run r.stats in QGIS to get all unique combinations of data values from 2 raster layers. The process runs, outputs an HTML file, and does not throw any errors. However the files are always blank, and the entire process runs in under 2 seconds (I would expect if it was actually doing the analysis to take much longer than 2 seconds.

I am using the tool in QGIS that is part of GRASS. The resulting Python code from running the tool is

```
r.stats input=Lanholder_proj,lossyear_proj separator="," null_value="*" nsteps=255 sort="asc" -1 -a -c -l x
```

I know this is vague information, but if I would love to see an example using any data on how to use r.stat to combine 2 datasets to calculate the area of all unique combinations.

Comment: Did you check the official manual page ? There are some examples provided https://grass.osgeo.org/grass80/manuals/r.stats.html